# How to check ios SDK version used to compile framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

As said at the title I have a framework and I need to check with iOS SDK version was used to compile it. Is there any command to check it? Or any other way.

Thanks

Comment: see this for help :[How to check the iOS SDK version used to compile .ipa or .app file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684501/how-to-check-the-ios-sdk-version-used-to-compile-ipa-or-app-file)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks, do you know if it is the same process for an .ipa as for a .framework?

Comment: may I know the name for which framework do you wantr

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the problem is that is a private one so I cannot find any info on the internet :(