# Check Build SDK Version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, itunes

With the new App Requirements and Guidelines from Apple, one of them is that Apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later.
My company has several apps on iTunes, and I was wondering if there is some way to see what SDK version a build was built with, either in iTunes or in the Organiser in Xcode.
Otherwise I guess the only option is to rebuild and upload apps that we haven't build for a while, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you have .ipa you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684501/how-to-check-the-ios-sdk-version-used-to-compile-ipa-or-app-file. When you archive the .ipa it includes extra keys from which you can determine the sdk version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999073/how-do-i-tell-which-version-of-xcode-which-sdk-built-an-xcarchive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement to use the iOS 13 SDK only applies to new submissions. Apps already on the App Store don't need to be updated.

If you submit a new version containing enhancements or bug fixes, then you need to use the iOS 13 SDK.

You do not need to submit an otherwise unchanged app simply to use the iOS 13 SDK.